# How to store books in couchdb?

Tags: database-design

I want to save some books in database. I'm interested in couchdb because it
can serve the content directly with html formatted.

The book size that will be stored is varying around 500Kb to 50Mb or more.
Every book will also store it's table of contents, author, publisher etc.
The books will be grouped by their category. And some big books is
divided into several volumes.

The main feature that will be provided is find book pages by keyword
which the user can do to all books in database or by filtering by it's
category or by book. I don't mind slow insert, because it will be done
occasionally.

Now, I'm in doubt about the design. I'm came up with two design with
it's view map function:

1. Store every book as a single document:

   The design look like this:

   ```
   {
     _id: "book name because it's unique",
     author: {
       name: "Some name",
       bio: "Author's biography if available"
     },
     contents: [
       {
         text: "some long text",
         page: 14
       }
     ]
     publisher: "Some information about publisher"
   }
   ```

   And the view map function look like this:

   ```
   function (doc) {
     if (doc._id && doc.contents) {
       for (var i = 0; i < doc.contents.length; ++i) {
         var page = doc.contents[i];
         emit([doc._id, page.page], {
           title: doc.title,
           content: page.text,
           page_number: page.page,
           author: doc.author
         });
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Split book, author, contents to it's own document:

   The book design look like this:

   ```
   {
     _id: "book:book's name",
     type: "book",
     publisher: "some information about publisher"
   }
   ```

   Author design:

   ```
   {
     _id: "author:author's name",
     type: "author",
     name: "author name",
     bio: "author biography",
     book_id: "book:book's name"
   }
   ```

   Content design:

   ```
   {
     _id: "page: unique id",
     type: "page",
     page: 1231,
     text: "the contents",
     book_id: "book:book's name"
   }
   ```

   And the view map function look like this:

   ```
   function (doc) {
     if (doc.type === "page") {
       emit([doc.book_id, doc._id], {
         book_id: doc.book_id,
         content: doc.text,
         page_number: doc.page
       });
     }
   }
   ```

So, which one is better? Or maybe you can suggest a better way to do this?
Or maybe SQL database is more suitable for books database with features
I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

i think both is usable.. if you are not emitting single words from a page.
i ran into trouble, emitting a huge amount of values (100.000+) within one document..

I personally like the possibility to have all informations within one document.. so there is no need to make more than one query f.e. 
But keep in mind: if you want to display the page in result, they keys( values) are getting quite big. 
if you regular use case is displaying only single pages.. the second one ist better.  and use include_docs=true for the page documents. (smaller search tree)

is "one long text" the page text, or are those the keywords to query ?

there are some other things to improve, but maybe you sepcify the searchable keywords first ..